# boost::function error

Tags: c++, function, boost

I have the following: (I want to pass `call_back` to another function from where it will be called)

```
boost::function<std::string (ResolverReply& reply)> call_back = boost::bind(&ResolverCommunicator::reply_call_back, *this, _1);
```

the signature of the passed function is:

```
std::string reply_call_back (ResolverReply& reply);  //Member function
```

and my compiler gives me this error:

```
error C2665: 'boost::bind' : none of the 3 overloads can convert parameter 2 from type 'ResolverCommunicator'
        c:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_44\boost\bind\bind.hpp(1480): could be 'boost::_bi::bind_t<R,F,L> boost::bind<std::string(__thiscall ResolverCommunicator::* )(ResolverReply &),ResolverCommunicator,boost::arg<I>>(F,A1,A2)'
        with
        [
            R=boost::_bi::unspecified,
            F=std::string (__thiscall ResolverCommunicator::* )(ResolverReply &),
            L=boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::list_av_2<ResolverCommunicator,boost::arg<1>>::B1,boost::_bi::list_av_2<ResolverCommunicator,boost::arg<1>>::B2>,
            I=1,
            A1=ResolverCommunicator,
            A2=boost::arg<1>
        ]
        c:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_44\boost\bind\bind_mf_cc.hpp(43): or       'boost::_bi::bind_t<R,F,L> boost::bind<std::string,ResolverCommunicator,ResolverReply&,ResolverCommunicator,boost::arg<I>>(R (__thiscall ResolverCommunicator::* )(B1),A1,A2)'
        with
        [
            R=std::string,
            F=boost::_mfi::mf1<std::string,ResolverCommunicator,ResolverReply &>,
            L=boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::list_av_2<ResolverCommunicator,boost::arg<1>>::B1,boost::_bi::list_av_2<ResolverCommunicator,boost::arg<1>>::B2>,
            I=1,
            B1=ResolverReply &,
            A1=ResolverCommunicator,
            A2=boost::arg<1>
        ]
        c:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_44\boost\bind\bind_mf_cc.hpp(54): or       'boost::_bi::bind_t<R,F,L> boost::bind<std::string,ResolverCommunicator,ResolverReply&,ResolverCommunicator,boost::arg<I>>(R (__thiscall ResolverCommunicator::* )(B1) const,A1,A2)'
        with
        [
            R=std::string,
            F=boost::_mfi::cmf1<std::string,ResolverCommunicator,ResolverReply &>,
            L=boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::list_av_2<ResolverCommunicator,boost::arg<1>>::B1,boost::_bi::list_av_2<ResolverCommunicator,boost::arg<1>>::B2>,
            I=1,
            B1=ResolverReply &,
            A1=ResolverCommunicator,
            A2=boost::arg<1>
        ]
        while trying to match the argument list '(std::string (__thiscall
 ResolverCommunicator::* )(ResolverReply &), ResolverCommunicator, boost::arg<I>)'
        with
        [
            I=1
        ]
```

Does anybody know what I have done wrong?

Comment: Aren't you supposed to pass `this` and not `*this` when binding member functions?

Comment: I tried with g++ and it's compiling without any error.

Answer (score 0):

Is `ResolverCommunicator` copy constructible (does it have publicly accessible copy constructor)? It is required if you are passing `*this` to `bind`:

```
boost::function<std::string (ResolverReply& reply)>
    call_back = boost::bind(
        &ResolverCommunicator::reply_call_back, 
        *this, // copy construtibility required here for *this
        boost::_1);
```

If no copy construction is available, use `boost::ref` on `*this` or just `this`. Take care of the instance life time then...

Edit: Hm, are the boost placeholders in the global namespace?